# Как переделать макрос excel, который скрывает строки по условию

Tags: excel, макросы, макрос

У меня есть макрос, который скрывает строки в excel если в нем есть вхождение таких слов как "мама" и/или "папа":

```
Sub СкрытьСтроки()
    Dim ra As Range, delra As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    СкрытьСтрокиСТекстом = Array("мама", "папа") 
    For Each ra In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        For Each word In СкрытьСтрокиСТекстом 
            If Not ra.Find(word, , xlValues, xlPart) Is Nothing Then
                If delra Is Nothing Then Set delra = ra Else Set delra = Union(delra, ra)
            End If
        Next word
    Next
    If Not delra Is Nothing Then delra.EntireRow.Hidden = True   
End Sub
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать этот макрос наоборот. Т.е. если в строке есть вхождение этих слов ("мама" и/или "папа"), то макрос их не скрывает, а скрывает другие строки, где эти слова не встречаются.
Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Инвертируйте условие проверки.

Comment: @Akina , при инвертации данное решение не совсем корректно. Объясню почему:
`1 строка: сын, дочь   
2 строка: мама, сын   
3 строка: папа, дочь`   

При вашем варианте, при инвертировании условий в массиве макроса необходимо прописать "сын", "дочь". При таком раскладе скроются все три строки из моего примера, хотя 2 и 3 строки должны остаться видимыми.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub СкрытьСтроки()
Dim a()
Dim bFlag As Boolean, j As Long
Dim ra As Range, delra As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    a = Array("мама", "папа")

    For Each ra In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        For j = 0 To UBound(a)
            If InStr(ra, a(j)) Then
                bFlag = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next j '   Next word -> Next j'

        If bFlag = False Then
            If delra Is Nothing Then Set delra = ra Else Set delra = Union(delra, ra)
        Else
            bFlag = False
        End If
    Next

    If Not delra Is Nothing Then delra.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Вложенный цикл лучше заменить на другой

```
j = -1

Do: j = j + 1
    If InStr(ra, a(j)) Then bFlag = True
Loop Until bFlag = True Or j = UBound(a)
```

Можно было по-другому: в начале обработки скрыть строки, в процессе формировать диапазон для отображения строк.

Comment: Большое спасибо, но у меня почему-то не получается... Я гуманитарий и во всех этих символах ничего не понимаю. Не могли бы вы откорректировать ваш ответ с окончательным вариантом макроса?

Comment: В Вашем примере. Изменял код "на коленке"

Comment: Если я пробую макрос по первому примеру, то эксель выделяет слово "word" и пишет ошибку:
`Compile error: </br>
Invalid Next control variable reference`

Comment: Я писал о примере в файле Excel

Comment: Странно, но я в файле excel и запустил этот макрос :)

Comment: Не поняли... Нужен  ВАШ ПРИМЕР В ФАЙЛЕ, чтобы в нем проверить работу макроса. Или предлагаете помогающим еще и примеры рисовать?